# datatables.net Server-side processing in C# Razor Core, DataTables warning: table id= Requested unknown parameter for row column datatables.net/tn/4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I am making Razor Core app.
For that, I reference datatables in Asp.Net MVC project: [jQuery Datatable Server Side Processing in Asp.Net MVC - Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14-BSUHvJ_0)

---

Reference Source code in the YT video description:

[image]

I keep getting this error:

DataTables warning: table id=employeetable - Requested unknown parameter 'EmployeeID' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in **capital case** and **lower case**.

---

In the
Reference Source code from youtube video The **data** in capital case like:

```
"data": "EmployeeID"
```

in the  `{ "data": "EmployeeID", "name": "EmployeeID" },`  column

[image]

But after looking into other sources, I discover that in Core project it should be **lower case**

---

Like here: [JQuery Datatable in ASP.NET Core – Server-Side Processing](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-core/)

[image]

---

Or here: [Server Side Rendering Of DataTables JS In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/server-side-rendering-of-datatables-js-in-asp-net-core/)

[image]